# Understanding the etymology of Persian "farāmoş", to forget

Tags: etymology

I'm having a hard time understanding the etymology of the Persian verb *farâmuš kardan*, meaning *to forget* in Persian.

- The infnitive kardan is often used to make verbs from nouns and
  adjectives, so for this part there's no problem.  the adjective here
  is *farâmuš*, and it translates as *forgotten*.  In the book of Horn,
  It is written  : *farâmuš, farâmušt, farâmušidan*, since the
  infinitive is formed with -idan in Persian, it made me think that a
  verb *farâmušidan* meant *to forget*. I didn't find any translation for
  neither mušidan and farâmušidan.
- Horn then states that the root of the word is formed with *pra* + marš-, mršyatē. It seems similar to me to English 'forget' since it shares the same prefix *pra-* with it. In English the pra- means "out, away" and get is considered as "having a hold on smth", so forget etymologically means " to lose hold on smth in someone's mind" whence to *forget*. However in Farsi the fra- prefix generally connotes frontwards direction/movement. I don't know if they are in the same context with english forget.
- I have no clue on the meaning of marš-, I looked on the internet and I found on PIE lexicon that marš- means "to falsify" in Proto Indo European, but I doubt that they are talking about the same marš- or if my source is correct.

If somebody has the time to explain me these etymological meanings and the semantics of this compound, it would be super

Comment: Inflected verb forms may become fossilized when the stem is forgotten or otherwise not recognizable and when the morphemes aren't productive anymore (I'm thinking of Ger *mögen*, *ich mag* "I like, like to", akin to En "may", and the once subjunctive construction *ich möchte* "I *would* like to, I want" that has had no real infinitive of its own, but dictionaries might index *möchten* to fit the pattern anyways, even if it virtually never used naturally; There are many more examples like that which might also not always come from one stem but a supplemental paradigm.

Comment: This is a duplicate from https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/cshvk3/understanding_the_etymology_of_persian_farāmoş_to/?utm_content=comments_view_all